# xfs acl not preserved after reboot

Tags: acl, xfs

I'm adding a new xfs partition (/home) to a  centos 7 server that has ext3 filesystem.
Old /home is ext3.

After mounting the new partition, I copied the info in the old home to the new home with rsync:

```
rsync -avAX --progress /home-old/ /home/
```

I verified the acls and they were copied correctly

```
#getfacl /home/www/index.php
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: home/www/index.php
# owner: myuser
# group: myuser
user::rw-
user:nginx:rwx
user:otheruser:rwx
user:other:r-x
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
```

But after rebooting the server, the files no longer have the acls

```
#/etc/fstab
LABEL=NEWHOME   /home   xfs defaults    0 0
```

I googled for a mount option to enable acls but what I read, is that acls are enabled by default.

What could be wrong? how can I preserve the copied acls between reboots?

```
# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
hcp1    121:1    0   99G  0 disk
xvda    202:0    0  100G  0 disk
├─xvda1 202:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─xvda2 202:2    0   99G  0 part /       (ext3)
xvdb    202:16   0    2G  0 disk
└─xvdb1 202:17   0    2G  0 part [SWAP]
xvdc    202:32   0  250G  0 disk
└─xvdc1 202:33   0  250G  0 part /home   (xfs)
```